# how do you tell a program to terminate?

Tags: python

I can't figure out how to tell a program to terminate in the actual code. The language I am using is python.

Comment: please provide your code example...along with any associated error messages

Comment: Do you ask how a basic Python code ends or how to force the ending of a program ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function `exit()` from `sys` library for exit the program before the end of the program, otherwise the program end at the end of program.

```
import sys
# ...
# Some statements
# ...
sys.exit("some error message")
# ...
# Some statements
# ...
```

for more information about `sys` module look the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/constants.html#exit)